# How to use the TTaskDialog?

Tags: delphi, ttaskdialog

How does one use the `TTaskDialog` class (in Delphi 2009 and later)? [The official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TTaskDialog) hasn't helped. In fact, you learn much more by examining the class using CodeInsight or the VCL source code. There are no pedagogical explanations there, but at least there are no errors either (well, [just a few](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3585867/how-to-verify-if-the-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-delphi-ttaskdialog)).

And just recently, I wondered how you could respond to hyperlink clicks in the dialog. Indeed, setting the `tfEnableHyperlinks` flag, you can include HTML hyperlinks in the dialog's textual parts. (Well, the doc's said about the flag: "If set, content, footer, and expanded text can include hyperlinks." Naturally, it is "obvious" that the links are implemented using the `<A` HTML element.) And I managed to figure out myself that you use the `OnHyperLinkClick` event to respond to clicks on hyperlinks. But this event is a `TNotifyEvent`, so how do you know what link was clicked? Well, the documentation said nothing about that, so I had to guess. Eventually I found out that the `URL` public property of the dialog is set, so I could do

```
procedure TmainFrm.TaskDialogHyperLinkClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TTaskDialog then
    with Sender as TTaskDialog do
      ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(URL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

The official documentation says, regarding this property:

> URL contains the URL for the Task
>   Dialog.

Now, you have to admit, that's a great explanation! But it is worse than this: not only does the documentation lack in explanations, it also contains errors. [For instance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TTaskDialog_Properties),

> ExpandButtonCaption: Additional information for this button.

That's not very accurate. What button? If you show the help for this particular property, [it says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TTaskDialog.ExpandButtonCaption)

> ExpandButtonCaption contains additional text to be displayed when the caption is expanded.

Not good either. What caption? A proper explanation would be

> ExpandButtonCaption is the text shown next to the button that lets the user expand the dialog to make it show more information. For instance, this property might be "More details".

At any rate, currently, I am trying to create a dialog with two command-link buttons. I know that the operating system can display these buttons with both a caption and a longer explanation, but I seem not to be able to make it work using the `TTaskButton`. The documentation [isn't great](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TTaskDialog.Buttons).

But instead of asking how to achieve this particular thing here at SO, I will ask another question:

> Is there any (unofficial) documentation for the TTaskDialog class?

Comment: I found a solution for the particular problem, though: `with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do begin Caption := 'The caption';CommandLinkHint := 'The explanation.'; end;` That wasn't too obvious, but it works...

Comment: Myself, I think it's just easier to write directly against the Win32 Api function which is pretty trivial to use.

Comment: @David: Yes, maybe I should just do that instead.

Comment: You need to degrade to something else if you want to support XP, so you'll have to do a bit of work anyway

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you can't find the documentation, then [write it](https://specials.rejbrand.se/TTaskDialog/):

## The Hello World of a Task Dialog

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'Hello World!';
    Text := 'I am a TTaskDialog, that is, a wrapper for the Task Dialog introduced ' +
            'in the Microsoft Windows Vista operating system. Am I not adorable?';
    CommonButtons := [tcbClose];
    Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

`Caption` is the text shown in the titlebar of the window, `Title` is the header, and `Text` is the body matter of the dialog. Needless to say, `Execute` displays the task dialog, and the result is shown below. (We will return to the `CommonButtons` property in a section or two.)

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

## Being a Well-Behaved Citizen

Of course, the task dialog will crash the program if running under Windows XP, where there is not task dialog API. It will also not work if visual themes are disabled. In any such case, we need to stick to the old-fashioned `MessageBox`. Hence, in a real application, we would need to do

```
if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
  with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
    try
      Caption := 'My Application';
      Title := 'Hello World!';
      Text := 'I am a TTaskDialog, that is, a wrapper for the Task Dialog introduced ' +
              'in the Microsoft Windows Vista operating system. Am I not adorable?';
      CommonButtons := [tcbClose];
      Execute;
    finally
      Free;
    end
else
  MessageBox(Handle,
             'I am an ordinary MessageBox conveying the same message in order to support' +
             'older versions of the Microsoft Windows operating system (XP and below).',
             'My Application',
             MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
```

In the rest of this article, we will assume that the [tax](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing) of backwards compatibility is being payed, and instead concentrate on the task dialog alone.

## Types of Dialogs. Modal Results

The `CommonButtons` property is of type `TTaskDialogCommonButtons`, defined as

```
TTaskDialogCommonButton = (tcbOk, tcbYes, tcbNo, tcbCancel, tcbRetry, tcbClose);
TTaskDialogCommonButtons = set of TTaskDialogCommonButton;
```

This property determines the buttons shown in the dialog (if no buttons are added manually, as we will do later on). If the user clicks any of these buttons, the corresponding `TModalResult` value will be stored in the `ModalResult` property as soon as `Execute` has returned. The `MainIcon` property determines the icon shown in the dialog, and should -- of course -- reflect the nature of the dialog, as should the set of buttons. Formally an integer, `MainIcon` can be set to any of the values `tdiNone`, `tdiWarning`, `tdiError`, `tdiInformation`, and `tdiShield`.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'The Process';
    Text := 'Do you want to continue even though [...]?';
    CommonButtons := [tcbYes, tcbNo];
    MainIcon := tdiNone; // There is no tdiQuestion
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrYes then
        beep;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

Below are samples of the remaining icon types (shield, warning, and error, respectively):

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

Finally, you should know that you can use the `DefaultButton` property to set the default button in the dialog box.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'The Process';
    Text := 'Do you want to continue even though [...]?';
    CommonButtons := [tcbYes, tcbNo];
    DefaultButton := tcbNo;
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrYes then
        beep;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

## Custom Buttons

You can add custom buttons to a task dialog. In fact, you can set the `CommonButtons` property to the empty set, and rely entirely on custom buttons (and un unlimited number of such buttons, too). The following real-world example shows such a dialog box:

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Title := 'Confirm Removal';
    Caption := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
    Text := Format('Are you sure that you want to remove the book file named "%s"?', [FNameOfBook]);
    CommonButtons := [];
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Remove';
      ModalResult := mrYes;
    end;
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Keep';
      ModalResult := mrNo;
    end;
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrYes then
        DoDelete;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

## Command Links

Instead of classical pushbuttons, the task dialog buttons can be command links. This is achieved by setting the `tfUseCommandLinks` flag (in `Flags`). Now you can also set the `CommandLinkHint` (per-button) property:

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Title := 'Confirm Removal';
    Caption := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
    Text := Format('Are you sure that you want to remove the book file named "%s"?', [FNameOfBook]);
    CommonButtons := [];
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Remove';
      CommandLinkHint := 'Remove the book from the catalogue.';
      ModalResult := mrYes;
    end;
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Keep';
      CommandLinkHint := 'Keep the book in the catalogue.';
      ModalResult := mrNo;
    end;
    Flags := [tfUseCommandLinks];
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrYes then
        DoDelete;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

The `tfAllowDialogCancellation` flag will restore the close system menu item (and titlebar button -- in fact, it will restore the entire system menu).

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

## Don't Throw Technical Details at the End User

You can use the properties `ExpandedText` and `ExpandedButtonCaption` to add a piece of text (the former) that is only displayed after the user clicks a button (to the left of the text in the latter property) to request it.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Title := 'Confirm Removal';
    Caption := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
    Text := Format('Are you sure that you want to remove the book file named "%s"?', [FNameOfBook]);
    CommonButtons := [];
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Remove';
      CommandLinkHint := 'Remove the book from the catalogue.';
      ModalResult := mrYes;
    end;
    with TTaskDialogButtonItem(Buttons.Add) do
    begin
      Caption := 'Keep';
      CommandLinkHint := 'Keep the book in the catalogue.';
      ModalResult := mrNo;
    end;
    Flags := [tfUseCommandLinks, tfAllowDialogCancellation];
    ExpandButtonCaption := 'Technical information';
    ExpandedText := 'If you remove the book item from the catalogue, the corresponding *.book file will be removed from the file system.';
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrYes then
        DoDelete;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

The image below shows the dialog after the user has clicked the button to reveal the additional details.

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

If you add the `tfExpandFooterArea` flag, the additional text will instead be shown in the footer:

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

In any case, you can let the dialog open with the details already expanded by adding the `tfExpandedByDefault` flag.

## Custom Icons

You can use any custom icon in a task dialog, by using the `tfUseHiconMain` flag and specifying the `TIcon` to use in the `CustomMainIcon` property.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Caption := 'About Rejbrand BookBase';
    Title := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
    CommonButtons := [tcbClose];
    Text := 'File Version: ' + GetFileVer(Application.ExeName) + #13#10#13#10'Copyright © 2011 Andreas Rejbrand'#13#10#13#10'http://english.rejbrand.se';
    Flags := [tfUseHiconMain, tfAllowDialogCancellation];
    CustomMainIcon := Application.Icon;
    Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

## Hyperlinks

You can even use HTML-like hyperlinks in the dialog (in `Text`, `Footer,` and `ExpandedText`), if you only add the `tfEnableHyperlinks` flag:

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Caption := 'About Rejbrand BookBase';
    Title := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
    CommonButtons := [tcbClose];
    Text := 'File Version: ' + GetFileVer(Application.ExeName) + #13#10#13#10'Copyright © 2011 Andreas Rejbrand'#13#10#13#10'<a href="http://english.rejbrand.se">http://english.rejbrand.se</a>';
    Flags := [tfUseHiconMain, tfAllowDialogCancellation, tfEnableHyperlinks];
    CustomMainIcon := Application.Icon;
    Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

Notice, however, that nothing happens when you click the link. The action of the link must be implemented manually, which -- of course -- is a good thing. To do this, respond to the `OnHyperlinkClicked` event, which is a `TNotifyEvent`. The URL of the link (the href of the a element, that is) is stored in the `URL` public property of the `TTaskDialog`:

```
procedure TForm1.TaskDialogHyperLinkClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TTaskDialog then
    with Sender as TTaskDialog do
      ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(URL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
    try
      Caption := 'About Rejbrand BookBase';
      Title := 'Rejbrand BookBase';
      CommonButtons := [tcbClose];
      Text := 'File Version: ' + GetFileVer(Application.ExeName) + #13#10#13#10'Copyright © 2011 Andreas Rejbrand'#13#10#13#10'<a href="http://english.rejbrand.se">http://english.rejbrand.se</a>';
      Flags := [tfUseHiconMain, tfAllowDialogCancellation, tfEnableHyperlinks];
      OnHyperlinkClicked := TaskDialogHyperlinkClicked;
      CustomMainIcon := Application.Icon;
      Execute;
    finally
      Free;
    end
end;
```

## The Footer

You can use the `Footer` and `FooterIcon` properties to create a footer. The `icon` property accepts the same values as the `MainIcon` property.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'A Question';
    Text := 'This is a really tough one...';
    CommonButtons := [tcbYes, tcbNo];
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    FooterText := 'If you do this, then ...';
    FooterIcon := tdiWarning;
    Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

Using the `tfUseHiconFooter` flag and the `CustomFooterIcon` property, you can use any custom icon in the footer, in the same way as you can choose your own main icon.

## A Checkbox

Using the `VerificationText` string property, you can add a checkbox to the footer of the task dialog. The caption of the checkbox is the property.

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'A Question';
    Text := 'This is a really tough one...';
    CommonButtons := [tcbYes, tcbNo];
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    VerificationText := 'Remember my choice';
    Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

You can make the checkbox initially checked by specifying the `tfVerificationFlagChecked` flag. Unfortunately, due to a bug (?) in the VCL implementation of the `TTaskDialog`, the inclusion of this flag when `Execute` has returned doesn't reflect the final state of the checkbox. To keep track of the checkbox, the application thus needs to remember the initial state and toggle an internal flag as a response to each `OnVerificationClicked` event, which is triggered every time the state of the checkbox is changed during the modality of the dialog.

## Radio Buttons

Radio buttons can be implemented in a way resembling how you add custom push buttons (or command link buttons):

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(self) do
  try
    Caption := 'My Application';
    Title := 'A Question';
    Text := 'This is a really tough one...';
    CommonButtons := [tcbOk, tcbCancel];
    MainIcon := tdiNone;
    with RadioButtons.Add do
      Caption := 'This is one option';
    with RadioButtons.Add do
      Caption := 'This is another option';
    with RadioButtons.Add do
      Caption := 'This is a third option';
    if Execute then
      if ModalResult = mrOk then
        ShowMessage(Format('You chose %d.', [RadioButton.Index]));
  finally
    Free;
  end
```

[image: Sample of a TTaskDialog]

Comment: Nice writeup.  +1 for the extra effort.

Comment: +1 to @Chris. You always post a nice comment when someone gets a lot of criticism (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017743/delphi-components-you-cant-live-without/3017810#3017810). There should be a badge for that, e.g. "comradeship", or "supportive".

Comment: Selfish idea: would you consider creating a component that degrades gracefully under Windows XP? I like the idea of the TMS component, but I already have a third-party package and don't want to add another... I can provide some help if you create a small google code project... :-)

Comment: @Leonardo: That wouldn't be difficult at all. (Not saying I will do it, though...)

Comment: +1 for Q&A; I've found TTaskDialog now and your article about it helped me a lot. Good job!

Comment: @Leonardo: Maybe you've discovered it for yourself by now, but there is [SynTaskDialog](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven). Its emulation doesn't cover everything Microsoft's task dialog can do and it looks a bit rough but it works.

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt - no, I haven't revisited this thought I meant to. Thanks!

Comment: hey 'Service Unavailable' for the link,

Comment: @PresleyDias: Must be my web hosting provider that experienced problems. I never remove stuff from my sites.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand : oh ok got it, it opens now

Comment: Hi, Andreas, could you take your excellent example over here? This answer as it stands is endangered to be closed as VLQ due to being `Link Only`.

Comment: Meanwhile the problem with the checkbox flag 'tfVerificationFlagChecked' seems to be fixed. I'm working with Delphi XE3 and it works just fine.

Comment: Embarcadero should use your code and reward you with a free license.

Comment: + 100 - this solves almost every of case of fancy message dialogues!!

Comment: "_There is no tdiQuestion_" -> Workaround: `MainIcon := 32514;`

Comment: This is the best answer on SO ever. I want to declare your honorific citizen of StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think that the `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled` check is required. Even after disabling `Themes` service in `services.msc` and disabling all the visual effects, it still shows up, not as nice, but still fully functional. So is the `ThememServices.ThememsEnabled` check really needed here? Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/MeLEoAK.png

Comment: @Coder12345: I think it was at the time I wrote this A (Delphi 2009 on Windows 7). It might not be needed today (Delphi 10.3 on Windows 10).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I tested this in details. On newer versions of Delphi `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled` is not required, it works without it even if themes are disabled, then it goes into "ugly mode" automatically. If compiled using older version of Delphi then it won't work not even in the "ugly mode". So it is better to leave it in the code to make the code compatible with all versions of Delphi, with this perhaps as a sidenote.

Answer (score 7):

This is old stuff, but I'm adding this here for completeness:

[Open Source SynTaskDialog unit for XP,Vista,Seven](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven)

`TTaskDialog` unit that works under XP (with VCL), but uses the system TaskDialog under Vista+.

Answer (score 4):

TMS Has a nice wrapper, and it also emulates the new behavior when run on XP.  It's a snap to drop-in. It's not free though, and doesn't really answer your "how to" question.

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/vtd.asp

They also have some articles where they discuss the dialog, and there's some source code that may be useful to you if you want to make your own wrapper.

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev5.asp

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev7.asp

Comment: Yes, I know of this wrapper, but I prefer to do things without 3rd-party components.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that task dialogs look good on XP. They look misplaced. The way to do it, IMHO, is to use task dialogs on Vista/7, and old-fashioned `MessageBox`es on XP, as I do at http://specials.rejbrand.se/TTaskDialog.

Comment: However, it's not breaking your app on XP. Even if Andreas doesn't think it's a bad idea.  The rest of the professional software community doesn't look too kindly on such a limitation.  If your software is at toy, then fine. is looking good more important to you, than complete functional breakage?

Comment: @Warren P: All my applications work perfectly on Windows XP. I always use `TTaskDialog` on Vista/7 and the `MessageBox` on XP. If you call that "breaking" the app on XP, then that is your (and Embarcadero's?) opinion.

Comment: TMS Task dialogs have some ugly issues when VCL Styles are used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my short documentation:

1. Don't use it, unless you don't want your application to work on XP.
2. Suggest improvements to the [delphi doc wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TTaskDialog) content, as others did, but note the phrase "Note:  Task Dialogs require Vista or Windows 7". that's code for "Don't use it!".  Basically, someone got the idea to fully support new Windows Vista dialogs, and the way it was done, was to write wrapper code that only calls the dialog APIs.  Since no fallback functionality is provided to you, you are out of luck on XP.

Comment: I always test the OS version and the availability of visual themes (yes, `TTaskDialog` doesn't work on Vista/7 without Aero enabled), and use a `TTaskDialog` if possible, and an ordinary `MessageBox` if not, as in http://specials.rejbrand.se/TTaskDialog. The wonderful visual style of the `TTaskDialog` makes it all worth this extra work. (But still, to be honest, I really do feel like "Who does use XP today?")

Comment: I don't think it is wise to blame Embarcadero for not making the `TTaskDialog` work on XP, because `TTaskDialog` is only a wrapper for an operating system API, and this is new to Vista. Yes, maybe it would have been good if the `TTaskDialog` did some custom processing on XP (or without visual themes), to simplify (marginally) the life of the developers (a simplification that wouldn't have been there if they used nothing but the native OS API), but I don't think you should require a wrapper to do so.

Comment: Disclosure: I work for Embarcadero.  But I still personally don't like components that don't work on all common windows versions. If you want to write your applications, to not work on XP fine.  But remember stackoverflow is not just about you and your problem, it's also about people who will come along later and read this information. So downvote away.  But others may come along and need to know this.

Comment: @Warren, see Andreas's writeup. His example shows how to make it fall-back nicely for XP.

Comment: @Warren P, I think the downvote is because of the tone of the post. Looks ranty :-)

Comment: Fortunately, XP is now history

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand is the check for `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled` really necessary? Please see my comment on your post - Screenshot again: https://i.imgur.com/MeLEoAK.png

Comment: @Coder12345: I think it was at the time of this post (Delphi 2009 on Windows 7). It might not be needed today (Delphi 10.3 on Windows 10).