# How can I make the 'Showmessage' dialog wider so it fits the text?

Tags: delphi, dialog

I'm showing where a file has been saved by using 'Showmessage' (in Win 7).
When the file path is long it gets truncated and elipsis get inserted.
eg
the path

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SubFolderOne\AnotherSubFolder\MyFile.csv
```

gets displayed as

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SubFolderOne\Ano...\MyFile.csv
```

Is there a way to make the message box wider and show all of the filename and path?

I have read this
http://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/displaying-long-non-breakable-text-file-path-in-messagedlg-truncationellipsis-issues/
which explains some of the reasoning and gives a rather unsatisfactory method for a TTaskDialog and I also I realise I could make my own form to act in the same way as Showmessage but I am wondering if there is a simpler solution using just Showmessage.

Comment: Split your string to several lines, like `Copy(s, 1, 32) + ' ... '#13 + Copy(s, 33, Length(s))`

Comment: Possible I guess. To make it look at all neat though I'd have to find the last backslash in the path that would fit across one line in the message window and split it there, but it still wouldn't read like a single filename and path

Comment: Design your own form instead of using `ShowMessage`; that form can do whatever you want. You can create your own function that accepts a string, creates the form, and displays the string in whatever manner you'd like.

Comment: See this great answer on TTaskDialog here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979556/how-to-use-the-ttaskdialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a simpler solution using just `ShowMessage`?

No there is not.

I can think of three obvious approaches, although doubtless there are more.

**Create your own dialog**

There's nothing particularly magical about a dialog. You can perfectly well create them yourself, and so have complete control over their appearance. The downside of course is that it can be hard to match the native platform appearance. Especially when you consider all the different Windows versions that you are typically expected to support.

**Use `CreateMessageDialog` and customise this Delphi form**

You can call the RTL function `CreateMessageDialog` to obtain a Delphi form that can be used to display your message dialog. You then have the opportunity to customize this dialog in any way you please.

**Use the task dialog API**

The task dialog API, introduced in Vista, affords control of the dialog width. Call `TaskDialogIndirect`, and specify a non-zero value for [`cxWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787473.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in my post I did conder those options and do already I make my own custom dialogs quite frequently. My question was really to do with Showmessage specifically and whether there was some property or method I could use to change its appearance.

Comment: That's simple. The answer is no. Such an answer tends not to be very well received, so I expanded.

Comment: So, did we answer your question then?

Comment: In the sense that I asked 'Can I' and you answered 'No' then yes you have answered it, thank you ! I'll just go with making my own form as usual. Sorry for the delay in accepting but I don't find navigating the site all that easy and sometimes lose track of my own posts so I can't see if anyone has answered it.

Comment: The most simple and quick solution is Petrus' - see below.

Comment: @semanino Quick yes, but with side effects that are likely undesirable

Answer (score 2):

Before ShowMessage put:

```
UseLatestCommonDialogs:= false;
```

I use Delphi 10.2 and it works.

Comment: One might want to put that line into the `.dpr` file; since `UseLatestCommonDialogs` is a global variable in `Vcl.Dialogs.pas`, it affects the whole application anyway once it is changed.
This is IMHO for sure the absolute quickest way to get rid of that nasty abbreviation "feature".